# Let client handle Django translations

Tags: python, django, po

Apologies in advance if the question has been asked before, couldn't find something similar.

So I have a Python Django (version 1.9.1) project with PO and MO files for translations. The client would like to easily edit them. Problem: each time we need to send them all PO files, they edit them with PO Edit software, send them back, we compile to MO files. Then we eventually commit & push the changes to a master branch with git. Then once we deploy to production, the last git version on master (containing the last PO MO files changes) is deployed to the client's server.

So I'm wondering if there is an existing system that allow to make this whole process automatic? Trying to not reinvent the wheel.

Basically the client would log into an admin interface, make some changes to sentences that can be translated, click a button, and that's it. It seems difficult to do that with the underlying PO MO file system though.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

[Django-Rosetta](http://django-rosetta.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) might do what you want, though you'll probably want to "checkpoint" the translations created by your customer every now and then by committing them to your repo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!